# Using source downloaded on windows on Linux platform

Tags: windows, source, text

I downloaded the Linux source code from the git repository on Windows and then copied the files to Fedora. I am unable to the build the kernel.

Is this, because I downloaded the source on Windows environment and then copied it to Linux?

The command

```
make defconfig
```

gives error message

```
lib/Kconfig.debug:1543: unknown option *the*
lib/Kconfig.debug:1546: syntax error
lib/Kconfig.debug:1545: unknown option *This*
lib/Kconfig.debug:1546: unknown option *in*
lib/Kconfig.debug:1549: syntax error
lib/Kconfig.debug:1548: unknown option *See*
lib/Kconfig.debug:1560: syntax error
lib/Kconfig.debug:1559: unknown option *If*
lib/Kconfig.debug:1569: syntax error
lib/Kconfig.debug:1568: unknown option *Say*
samples/Kconfig:23: syntax error
samples/Kconfig:22: unknown option *If*
samples/Kconfig:50: syntax error
samples/Kconfig:49: unknown option *If*
make[1]: *** [defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [defconfig] Error 2
[adminuser@localhost linux]$ _
```

The complete error message was too long basically says about syntax error in Kconfig.debug file ( unknown option ).

I may have to download the entire source code again if it is so.

Comment: What error messages are you seeing. Can you document the process that you have attempted so far? Thanks.

Comment: How was the source code provided? In a zip/gz/tar file, or as plain text? If it is plain text, then Windows can add characters that need to be removed.

Comment: It was downloaded as plain text.

Comment: what about copy paste test instead of screenshot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows adds characters to files. If you want to see them, open the file in an editor on Linux such as vi and look at the end of the line. You'll see at the end of each line `^M`

If you run dos2unix on the source file, then it will convert it to a format that Linux is happy with. dos2unix should be in /usr/bin. So:

```
dos2unix file_downloaded > file_downloaded.unix
mv file_downloaded.unix file_downloaded
```

And try running make again.

Comment: Thank you Warwick. I executed the command dos2unix on all the files under the download file.

Answer (score 1):

Source is nothing more than a set of text files or even a single text file. The words in it won't change when you download it on windows. If you download a source file for linux, it will work for a linux. I say "a linux" because there are many ways to configure linux and they can all behave in very different ways. Once you compile the source into a binary, that is when it will become incompatible, even between different linux machines if the cpu architectures are different.

Short answer, no it doesn't matter.

As Warwick said, we can help you more if you give us more information on what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you Evan, do the thinks like file format need to be changed for test and bash files before using them on Linux platform?